# How can I dynamically write to Row 0 using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am writing to excel using Java & Apache POI. To create the first row in my Excel Sheet (to show the column names / headers) I am currently creating an array of strings, and then iterating through each value in the array to populate row 0 in my excel sheet. This works fine, but I would like to remove this array so it can pull in the column names from my database. There are over 30 column names but I have shortened below for brevity. I need to set the cell value as the DB column name. Rather than stating each of the fields, how can I dynamically update row 0 with the columns from my database?

```
List<?> cases = (List<?>) model.get("cases");
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Cases");
String[] columns = { "Case ID", "Acknowledgement Received Date", "Actual Amount Returned"};

    Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
        cell.setCellValue(columns[i]);
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
    }
```

Comment: OK. But what is your question?

Comment: Apologies, I have edited and stated my question clearly now. My question is rather than stating each of the fields, how can I dynamically update row 0 with the columns from my database?

Comment: That depends on what kind of database you use, where the columns come from, which API you use to read data from your database, etc. Do you use a relational database? Do you use JDBC? Are these the columns of a single table? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can pull all columns names from your database using the getMetadata method of the result set.

More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData())

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResultSetMetaData`.

```
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData()
```

where rs is an instance of `ResultSet`

Then you can do something like this:

```
Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
for (int i = 0; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(i);
    cell.setCellValue(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
}
```

PS: You can create some function `getLabel` to convert Snake case into Title case and do

```
cell.setCellValue(getLabel(rsmd.getColumnName(i)));
```